# is it possible to write a dockerfile without registry in FROM statements?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

For example, I have a base dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
...
```

which I build `docker build -t my-base`, then build a second dockerfile:

```
FROM my-base
...
```

which works because `my-base` is available locally.  However, if I push these to a registry, it seems I am forced to replace the second docker file with:

```
FROM my-dockerhub-accountname/my-base
...
```

or if not using dockerhub:

```
FROM 1234.myregistryprovider/something/my-base
...
```

And likewise doing a `docker push -t my-dockerhub-accountname/my-base` or `1234.myregistryprovider/something/my-base` for the first image.

But docker is only ever connected to one registry (this still applies if it was not), why do these registry provder uris have to poison the docker files I write?  This makes doing CI considerably harder, binding whatever registry provider we choose to declarations in source code.

By comparison, when I reference a nuget/npm package, I do so by package name while registry is handled by the package source manager.  It does not and should not come into the question :/

Is there a way to avoid all this?

Comment: This is not possible in Docker.  The "one registry" it's connected to is _always_ `docker.io`.  Correspondingly, image names like `ubuntu:18.04` unambiguously refer to `docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04` and aren't installation-dependent.

Comment: So having the registry URL as part of the FROM statement is essentially part of the docker spec, even if it's implicitly prefixed with docker.io/username?